# Resize a raster background image using Paper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, html5-canvas

I am trying to add a background image to a canvas element with a script tag in the bottom of my HTML.

The output of this code is a small version, like a single tile, of the larger image. In the inspector, the canvas has been processed already so there is no way to control the image size with css.

Here is the javascript:

```
    window.onload = function() {
        // plain image coming server side 
        var crag_image = $('#last-upload').attr('src');
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        paper.setup(canvas);

        // Let's get layers working
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src =  crag_image;
        img.id = "background-crag";
        var layer = new paper.Layer();
        var raster = new paper.Raster(img);

        // End Layers

        var secondLayer = new paper.Layer();
        secondLayer.activate();

        var myPath = new paper.Path();
        myPath.strokeColor = 'red';
        myPath.strokeWidth = 2.5;


        // Draw the view:
        paper.view.draw();

        var tool = new paper.Tool();

        tool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
            myPath.add(event.point);
        }

        tool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
          myPath.add(event.point);
          // Update the content of the text item to show how many
          textItem.content = 'Segment count: ' + myPath.segments.length;
        }

        // When the mouse is released, simplify the path:
        function onMouseUp(event) {
          var segmentCount = path.segments.length;
          myPath.simplify(10);
          myPath.fullySelected = true;
          var newSegmentCount = myPath.segments.length;
          var difference = segmentCount - newSegmentCount;
          var percentage = 100 - Math.round(newSegmentCount / segmentCount * 100);
        }
   }
```

An update:

```
var raster = new paper.Raster(img); //works
```

If I try to expand the constructor as per the reference it then fails on what the view is.

```
var raster = new paper.Raster({
  source: img.src,
  position: view.center
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here

```
img.src =  crag_image;
```

is loading an image and then again loading the same image in raster. The raster sits on top of the same image and so you don't understand the difference.

```
var raster = new paper.Raster({
  source: img.src, // loading the image again ?
  position: paper.view.center
});
```

Instead what you want to do is replace this

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src =  crag_image;
        img.id = "background-crag";
        var layer = new paper.Layer();
        var raster = new paper.Raster(img);
```

with

```
var raster = new paper.Raster({
  source: crag_image, //notice here
  position: paper.view.center
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The name scoping in the docs or my code is off, this fixes the problem.

```
var raster = new paper.Raster({
  source: img.src,
  position: paper.view.center
});
```